# Simple oleDB Connection to database on web server

Tags: c#, oledb

My local ISP has great deals on personal web space and usually users use it to host their websites , but the ISP also states you can host a database on it. Now thus far i can connect to a accdb File locally on my HDD but how would the connection string look like if in wish to access the file on ftp-like web server? If would receive ip address and login credentials from my isp.

```
string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OlEDB.12.0;DataSource =...";
oleDbConnection cnMyConnection = new oleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is `OleDbConnection` not `oleDbConnection` by the way. C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes thats correct i was just in a hurry when typing. :)